# Como fazer um CircleProgress em Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estou programando em `Xamarin.Android` e preciso de um `progressbar` (ou algo do tipo) circular que realmente mostre algum progresso, tentei usar o `ProgressBar` mesmo, mas ele só mostra progresso na horizontal, no modo circular ele fica girando apenas, alguém sabe como posso resolver isso? Pode ser desde modificar o `ProgressBar` já existente (não manjo muito disso ainda pois sou iniciante) ou indicar outra coisa.

Já tentei usar o RadialProgress, mas não curti o "tema" dele (muito arredondado a barra de progresso) e também (pelo que vi) não há como mudar a cor do texto que fica dentro dela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já consegui resolver, usei o `Xamarin Bindings` para isso, não o conhecia muito bem, mas ele é bem simples e objetivo. Peguei essa biblioteca feita em `Java Android`: https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress e transformei o `.aar` dela num `.dll` com o `Xamarin Bindings` (tentei com um `.jar` anteriormente, mas não funcionou pois ele pega apenas as classes, o `.aar` empacota tudo, inclusive layouts e coisas externas que a biblioteca depende). 
Mais informações aqui: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/